# Does the Jacobian of curvilinear coordinates equal to the product of the magnitudes of the normal vectors?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates, jacobian, cylindrical-coordinates

I have observed that the Jacobian of the cylindrical and spherical coordinates is equal to the product of the magnitudes of the normal vectors. Is this true for all coordinate systems?

i.e.: $$\frac{\partial(x,y,z)}{\partial(u,v,w)} = \lvert \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial u} \rvert \lvert \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial v} \rvert\lvert \frac{\partial \mathbf r}{\partial w} \rvert$$

Comment: For *orthogonal* coordinates, yes (at least if you take the *absolute value* of the Jacobian determinant).

Comment: Just to be clear, when the coordinate system is not orthogonal, no, it is not true except by accident (when mapping $9$ dimensions onto $1$ continuously, you have to overlap, which occasionally produces meaningless coincidences).

Comment: Thanks!!! It took me a while but I actually managed to prove it :) I think...